# Why isn't "chez" used as a preposition in English?

Tags: loanwords, french

From consulting a number of online *English* dictionaries, "chez" means "in the home of" or "at the home of" in French. So, for example, "Chez Panisse" translates to "at the home of Panisse".

But, as far as I can tell, everyone treats it to mean "the house of" without any leading preposition. For example, if that's where you were going to dinner, I don't think anyone would say, "We're going Chez Panisse tonight".

If that's the normal English usage, why does every English dictionary define it as "at the home of"? If that were the case, wouldn't "We're going to Chez Panisse," read like "We're going to at the home of Panisse"?

Comment: *"Chez Panisse"* is the name of a restaurant. Names get treated differently.   If "In and Out" was the name of a restaurant, we'd say "We're going to eat at In and Out", even though we'd never say "We're eating at in my house tonight".

Comment: "Chez" isn't really a word in US English.  Aside from people who speak French, most know it only as a part of a name for a (presumably fancy French) restaurant, and interpret it to mean, roughly, "house of".  You can complain all you want, but these are the facts.

Comment: To English speakers (who don't know French), *chez* is roughly equivalent to *maison*.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks -- _chez_ is not used in English (British English in my case). People are free to insert French/Swahili/Urdu words into an English sentence wherever they want, but it doesn't magically transform them into English words.

Comment: Such expressions *are* used by native English speakers to each other in Ottawa, where there is a lot of French spoken, and almost certainly in Montreal (I am referring only to native English speakers), simply because it is more economical than saying *to the home of* or something similar, and there is no danger of being misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may depend on the education/reading level of the speaker. In English, there is nothing wrong with saying "We're having dinner *chez* the Bakers tonight," or even "... dinner chez Baker", and those usages are the one I come across the most.  It wouldn't make sense to say "We're having dinner *at chez* the Bakers' tonight," when the *chez* would be redundant.

I've never heard anyone use it with a preposition at all, in fact, though I'll take your word for the fact that some do.

If they use the preposition "to", then they don't understand what "chez" is supposed to be doing in the sentence.  "We're going *to chez* the Baker's tonight," again makes *chez* redundant.

I suppose some could say, "We're having dinner chez the Baker's house," when *house* would be redundant.  Again, I've never heard it misused that way, but I grant that it probably happens.

If your friends happen to have the surname "Panisse", then there would be nothing wrong with saying "We're going *chez Panisse* tonight."  In my other examples, I avoid using the word "go" because it's ambiguous: it refers both to a future tense construction, as in "I'm going to stay right here", and to travel, as in "Where are you going?" "We're going to the bowling alley."

If you'd like to edit your question to avoid the verb "to go" and proper nouns with the word "Chez" in them, it might result in fewer sidebars. On the other hand, it might result in the question becoming moot, also.

If you have other examples of cases you've observed where the speaker clearly meant "the house of...", as in (for example), "I just watched chez Bakers burn down," meaning, "I watched the Bakers' house burn down", that might help. But in my experience, the dictionaries are correct, and the speaker (in the case of the usage in this last example) would be mistaken.

Comment: jaxter, do you really know people who say things like "We're having dinner _chez_ the Bakers tonight"? As in, "Pretentious, moi?" I would run a mile.

Comment: @jaxter I might be tempted to slap someone across the face if they ever said that.

Comment: @William have you never shopped *chez Target?*

Comment: @TonyK Well, no more pretentious than using the word, "moi", but among friends who know the meaning, it is self-deprecating, as if to suggest that they _know_ they're pretentious, and they _know_ that makes them slightly abrasive, and they _know_ people make fun of them for it. They're signalling of all this with the choice of "chez". So, it's not really about the simple expectation of hospitality somewhere. It's about making fun of yourself. Everyone understands that they're not actually a character in a 1930's movie, after all. But you can always pretend that you are.

Comment: @TonyK (Better get your sneakers on...) To answer your question, I _do_ know people who use the word "chez", but it's reserved for close friends, and mostly those who also speak some French, and are a bit _Francophile_.  I happen to be half-Belgian, so I'm not as uncomfortable with cross-cultural adoption/pollination as most Americans.  Europeans are a little more forgiving / indulgent.
I think phoog makes a good point, though - it's usually _because_ it's (fake) pretentious that people do it.

Comment: @phoog Pronounced, of course, /ʃeɪ tɑrˡʒeɪ/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *mais bien sur* (the English accent in your IPA is noted!).  Jaxter: everyone I know who says *chez Target* or any variation thereon does so in joking mock pretension.  Which may itself be pretentious, I suppose.

Comment: jaxter, if you put it in italics to let us know that you are pronouncing it the French way, surely you have to put it lower case? As in _francophile_?

Answer (score 0):

"Chez Panisse" is the name of the restaurant, so you need an additional preposition.

Comment: Sure, but there are non-proper noun examples as well. If I wanted to jokingly refer to going to my friend Fred's house, I could say I was, "going to chez Fred." I wouldn't say, "I'm going chez Fred."

Comment: The key word there is "jokingly." The joke is that Fred's place is some fancy establishment called "Chez Fred."

Comment: @munificent Maybe _you_ wouldn't say "I'm going chez Fred", but that (see my Answer) is probably due to a confounding of the usage of the verb "go" in the sentence.  Would you say "We're playing poker _at chez_ Fred tonight", or "We're playing poker _chez_ Fred tonight"?  I've never heard the former used, for my part.

Comment: I'm not half-Belgian, but I agree entirely with jaxter here. If someone said, “I'm going to chez Fred tonight” (and _Chez Fred_ is not the name of a French restaurant), then I would definitely be judging them with all my inwardly pompous might. I might (at least half-jokingly) say that I was dining chez Fred tonight, but **never** that I was going to chez Fred or dining at chez Fred.

Answer (score -2):

We actually don't speak French. That's why that word is only used in proper names (usually of French restaurants).

Comment: As phoog points out in his comment, "...chez Target" is fairly common usage. I've also heard "...chez Talbot's" ("tall-bohz"). Both are parodies; one parodying those who attempt to downplay the frugality of Target shoppers, and the other parodying the elite (in the speaker's eyes) who shop at Talbot's.

Comment: @jaxter Chez is not an English word. I encourage all people who would insist on using 'chez' to just go ahead and speak French. Don't bother with English.